# What is the timespan type of max-age in the HTTP response header? Seconds, minutes?

Tags: http, httpwebresponse, response-headers

In the HTTP response header for my website it is returning a header that contains 
the following value.

```
"Cache-Control: max-age=3600"
```

Is 3600 in seconds or minutes?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

delta seconds. http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.3

> max-age
>
> Indicates that the client is willing to accept a response whose age is no greater than the specified time in seconds...

Answer (score 12):

It's in seconds, so the value you quoted corresponds to 1 hour.

Comment: was confused at first but this clarifies it, thank you for the straightforward answer